# Merge two dataframes with different Date Time Indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes with time index but with different scale. The first has data every 30 mins every day and the other has just one data per day. I want to fill the first dataframe with the values of the second and keep the shape of the first dataframe.

first:

```
2019-08-26 13:00:00 a 1
2019-08-26 13:30:00 b 2
2019-08-26 14:00:00 c 3
2019-08-26 14:30:00 d 4
2019-08-26 15:00:00 e 5
```

second:

```
2019-08-25 X
2019-08-26 Y
2019-08-27 Z
```

wanted result:

```
2019-08-26 13:00:00 a 1 Y
2019-08-26 13:30:00 b 2 Y
2019-08-26 14:00:00 c 3 Y
2019-08-26 14:30:00 d 4 Y
2019-08-26 15:00:00 e 5 Y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a temporary merge `key` in `df1` by normalising the index of `df1` then you should be able to `merge` `df1` with the other dataframe `df2` based on this `merge` key:

```
df1.assign(key=df1.index.normalize())\
   .merge(df2, left_on='key', right_index=True, how='left').drop('key', 1)
```

---

```
                     A  B  C
2019-08-26 13:00:00  a  1  Y
2019-08-26 13:30:00  b  2  Y
2019-08-26 14:00:00  c  3  Y
2019-08-26 14:30:00  d  4  Y
2019-08-26 15:00:00  e  5  Y
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to put the previous answer into perspective. Shubham Sharma's 'magic' line worked for me in the following context:

1. Convert the `Date` column to `pandas.Timestamp` object using the appropriate input format, so as to be able to apply the `normalize()` function to it - if it is not in this format, an exception will be raised.
2. Set the `Date` column as index.
3. Use Shubham Sharma's 'magic' line from the previous answer.

The code might look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['2019-08-26 13:00:00', 'a', 1],
                    ['2019-08-26 13:30:00', 'b', 2],
                    ['2019-08-26 14:00:00', 'c', 3],
                    ['2019-08-26 14:30:00', 'd', 4],
                    ['2019-08-26 15:00:00', 'e', 5]], columns=['Date', 'A', 'B'])

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df1.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['2019-08-25', 'X'], ['2019-08-26', 'Y'], ['2019-08-27', 'Z']], columns=['Date', 'A'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Now comes Shubham Sharma's magic line
df3 = df1.assign(key=df1.index.normalize()).merge(df2, left_on='key', right_index=True, how='left').drop('key', 1)

# Set column names (except the index) to A, B and C
df3.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the answer :)